# ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" Prerequisite not available in a ClickOnce Deployment

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I’m trying to utilize the ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" in my application but I’m not seeing the option under available perquisites. How do I get that option to show In Visual Studio 2008. This is for a ClickOnce deployment btw, and the below image is just to illustrate where ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" is to go once its there. Thanks.

[image]
<sub>(source: [windowsclient.net](http://windowsclient.net/sitefiles/1000/wpf/presents/103_6.png))</sub>

Comment: Jim, could you please tell us what that screen shot is from? Maybe even tell us what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything specific. I would just prefer my clients to use a subset of the .NET framework so they don't need to go through a 30 minute download if they don't already have it installed. That pic is from http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-intro-client-profile.aspx

Comment: Oh, is this from a ClickOnce  installer? I didn't see the tag. I suggest you edit your subject or question to say that this is about clickOnce.

Comment: Hi Jim, did you check the web page I posted below? I think it addresses also your ClickOnce scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you installed [Service Pack 1 for Vistual studio 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)?

Comment: Well I already had it installed as it came with my version of VS2008. But I ran through it anyway and it was there! Thanks fretje.

Answer (score 3):

The installer for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 is not included in the VS2008 SP1 installer due to size restrictions.

For a workaround on how to actually include it in your setup project, refer to this page: http://blogs.msdn.com/vsto/archive/2008/11/18/how-to-include-net-framework-3-5-sp1-with-your-installer.aspx

Comment: Thanks Julio, that web site was awesome. It answered what would have been my next question. Which was how to include the .NET framework on my actual install media. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just to add my two cents. After installing SP1 for Studio 2008 I still don't have .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile available as prerequisite.

But If I select .net client profile and .net framework 3.5 sp1 then .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile gets installed.

I suspect this is a glitch in studio 2008, but apparently it works.